# Cast IList<Object> to IList<CustomObject>?

Tags: c#, json, object, casting, javascriptserializer

I created a generic function that retreives a JSON and parses it:

```
    public IList<Object> RetrieveView(string result)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        IList<Object> values = ser.Deserialize< IList<Object> >(result);

        return values;
    }
```

The problem that i have alot of Classes that uses this.
for example when i try to use this:

```
IList<Receipt> receipts = (IList<Receipt>)RetrieveView(result);
```

I get `InvalidCastException` `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList[Receipt]'.`

Anyway to keep my function Generic and be able to cast it to all of my classes/models?

Comment: what does your JSON look like and your `Reciept` class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make your function generic:

```
    public IList<T> RetrieveView<T>(string result)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        IList<T> values = ser.Deserialize< IList<T> >(result);

        return values;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

If the object is deserialized as Receipt, you could use Enumerable extensions.

```
IList<Receipt> receipts = RetrieveView(result).Cast<Receipt>().ToList();
```